# Syslog console and file

Tags: syslog

I want to log everything to syslog in my application. I will be logging mostly at two levels. Info and debug. Debug messages I do not want end users to be able to see or access. As such these messages will be caught with the `syslog.conf` to a special folder.

My question is can I log other messages to console and to the messages file? My though was the following but this does not work as I expected.

```
#  /etc/syslog.conf     Configuration file for busybox's syslogd utility

*.debug     /var/log/debug

*.info      /var/log/info
*.info      /dev/consol
```

Comment: Also, double check that you don't have the typo `/dev/consol` as opposed to `/dev/console` in your configuration file.

Answer (score -1):

As per [`man 3 syslog`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) make sure the "priority" value is set correctly when calling `syslog()`.

A few useful snippets from the man page:

> The `priority` argument is formed by ORing together a `facility` value and a `level` value (described below).  If no `facility` value is ORed into  `priority`, then the default value set by `openlog()` is used, or, if there was no preceding `openlog()` call, a default of `LOG_USER` is employed.

and

> Values for `facility`:
> The `facility` argument is used to specify what type of program is logging the message. This lets the configuration file specify that messages from different facilities will be handled differently.
>
> - `LOG_AUTH`       security/authorization messages
> - `LOG_AUTHPRIV`   security/authorization messages (private)
> - `LOG_CRON`       clock daemon (cron and at)=
> - `LOG_DAEMON`     system daemons without separate facility value
> - `LOG_FTP`        ftp daemon
> - `LOG_KERN`       kernel messages (these can't be generated from user processes)
> - `LOG_LOCAL0` through `LOG_LOCAL7`
>   reserved for local use
> - `LOG_LPR`        line printer subsystem
> - `LOG_MAIL`       mail subsystem
> - `LOG_NEWS`       USENET news subsystem
> - `LOG_SYSLOG`     messages generated internally by syslogd(8)
> - `LOG_USER` (default)
>   generic user-level messages
> - `LOG_UUCP`       UUCP subsystem
>
> Values for `level`:
> This determines the importance of the message. The levels are, in order of decreasing importance:
>
> - `LOG_EMERG`      system is unusable
> - `LOG_ALERT`      action must be taken immediately
> - `LOG_CRIT`       critical conditions
> - `LOG_ERR`        error conditions
> - `LOG_WARNING`    warning conditions
> - `LOG_NOTICE`     normal, but significant, condition
> - `LOG_INFO`       informational message
> - `LOG_DEBUG`      debug-level message
>
> The function `setlogmask(3)` can be used to restrict logging to specified levels only.